# How to make a call in Magento to an external web service?

Tags: web-services, soap, erp, magento-1.8

I want to call an external web service when user find a product by CatalogSearch. Any idea to do this? I have a SOAP function to call at my ERP, but i don\’t know where i can put this function to call my web service.

Exactly I have a product catalog in my ERP. In Magento users search SKU number in the search input of the header in the Magento catalog search, and i would like to find the product with that SKU in my ERP.

Please help me and sorry for my english,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to :

1. Create a Magento Module;
2. Create a new Helper;
3. Add your ERP function to the Helper;
4. Call your helper function (something like Mage::getHelper('path/to/helper')->MyERPFunction();

Comment: Thanks flebel. You know about any tutorial or documentation to create my own helper?

Comment: You could take a look at this series of tutorial : http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5